# Как в cookie хранить значение checkbox, чтобы у сайта была возможность вкл темный режим django

Tags: python, html, django, веб-программирование, django-view

Я новичок и **хочу в сайте сделать темный режим** любим способом, будто с помощью django или js
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну, так чем мы вам можем помочь? Сначало лучше изучите js так как django просто помогает сделать админку сайту и ничего более. Всё другое делаеться на js, css, html

Comment: Здраствуйте! я сайт уже закончил, только осталось сделать так что, когда я включил темный режим, он после перезагрузки сайта не выключался. Может вы знайте как это сделать?
p.s я добавил картинки

Comment: Я только слышал о том на каком языке сайт сохраняет информацию в куки но не более.

Comment: спасибо вам в любом случае)))

Comment: @VaheBasmajyan, можно не в куках хранить, а в localStorage, как было показано в ответе ниже. Но в любом случае, там где у вас кнопка с темной темой нужно в js сделать сохранение состояния (в куки или в localStorage). А при загрузке страницы через js анализировать. Однако... localStorage находится только на стороне клиента, поэтому если у вас тема генерируется на стороне сервера, то тогда проще с куками работать. А если все темы доступны на клиентской стороне, то можно и с localStorage работать

Comment: когда checkbox в положении checked  в css меняется темя 
вот код. СпасиБО! вы меня помогли))
.checked[type='checkbox']:checked~section p {
  color: #fff;
}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вот так решился моя проблема с темным режимом

```
function on(){
    localStorage.setItem('dark',0)
}
function off(){
    localStorage.setItem('dark',1)

}

if (localStorage.getItem('dark') == 0) {
    document.write('<input id="boccheck" onclick="off()"  class="checked" type="checkbox">')
    }
else{
    document.write('<input id="boccheck" onclick="on()" checked  class="checked" type="checkbox">')
}
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском!  Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1275914/420098))

Answer (score 1):

Пища для размышления

```
var isFirst = localStorage.getItem('isFirstTime');
if (isFirst === null || isFirst === '') {
localStorage.setItem('isFirstTime', 1);
alert('первый раз здесь');
}
else{
alert('не первый раз ты здесь');
}

// чтобы удалить запись - delete localStorage.isFirst;
```